# Кто-нибудь сталкивался с функцией, которая бы позволяла проверять, сколько процентов видео просмотрел пользователь?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как можно вычисллить, сколько процентов видео просмотрел пользователь? Не пролистал, а именно просмотрел.
Не могу найти похожую реализацию на React

Comment: в каком виде видео встроено? хотя мб и не суть. таймером проверяйте позицию. будут переходы в видео больше, чем времени прошло между тиками, значит перемотал.

Answer (score 4):

У `<video>` есть события, которые вы можете использовать:

- `play` - когда видео начинает проигрываться
- `seeking` - когда видео начинает проматываться
- `ended` - когда видео закончилось

Подробнее здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

В событии `play` вы запоминаете текущую позицию видео (если это начало - то будет позиция 0). В событиях `seeking` и `ended` - вы можете снова проверить текущую позицию видео и узнать сколько времени проигрывалось видео, а точнее определить интервал с какой по кукую позицию пользователь смотрел. Теоретически вы можете по этим событиям определить и запомнить какие именно куски из видео пользователь посмотрел, а затем объединяя их (алгоритмически "накладывая друг на друга"), вычислить сколько процентов от общего объёма пользователь просмотрел.